# How do I reduce my load on Google cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

my Google cloud SQL facing large incoming connections. I need to reduce the SQL load. Is there anyway? when I search for load balancing it saying about compute engine load balancing. Please suggest me a way to reduce the load in my Google cloud SQl. I am using compute engine. Thank you for your time.

Comment: where from this connections are coming? isn't it your app? if so, just reduce amount of connections in your code (use caching, for example)

Comment: You can try using a read replica as well: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/replication/create-replica

Comment: My SQL server is connected with compute engine.

Comment: @DineshDhananjayan are you still encountering any issues? is, can you elaborate more on your use case?

Comment: Is it possible to implement load balancing in cloud SQL?

Comment: @DineshDhananjayan implementing a Google Load Balancer for Google Cloud SQL is not available. However, you can submit a feature request about it in this Public Issue Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/list